# Normalize a rotation around the Z-axis (issue with GLM)

Tags: 2d, mathematics, transformation

I'm trying to undo some transformations coming from an external tool*. I'm getting different results depending on subtle differences in the input and wondering how to convert to a rotation about the Z-axis only.

The transformations are expressed as a `matrix = translation * rotation * -translation`.  I want to decompose the resulting matrix into a single translation and rotation around Z -- I know this is possible given the source material (2D plane).

My problem is coming from GLM `decompose`.  Given a matrix that looks like this:

```
[         -0.5 |     0.866025 |            0 |            0 ]
[    -0.866025 |         -0.5 |            0 |            0 ]
[            0 |            0 |            1 |            0 ]
[            0 |            0 |            0 |            1 ]
```

If I call `decompose`, then take the eulerAngles of the Rotation I end up with either:

- (            0,           -0,      2.09439 ) from quat(          0.5,            0,     0.866025,            0 )
- (      3.14159,       1.0472,      3.14159 ) from quat(          0.5,            0,            0,     0.866025 )

The difference depends on how the matrix was generated, whether the rotation was 120degrees or -240degrees. The display must be clipping the floating point, introducing a subtle change.

I'm assuming both these rotations are actually the same.

**How do I force/convert the result to be a rotation about the Z axis only.**

---

**The external tool is Inkscape which uses the CSS/SVG function `rotate(r, cx, cy)` instead of a rotation and transform.  That function results in the matrix: translate(cx,cy,0) * rotate(r, (0,0,1)) * translate(-cx,cy,0)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no shearing in play, then `Atan2(matrix[0].y, matrix[0].x)` gives you the angle of rotation about the z axis in radians.

This is because the first column gives you the direction that the local x-axis points after rotation. If it's (1, 0) then there's no rotation (or a multiple of 2 pi). If it's (0, 1) there's been a 90 degree rotation, etc. `Atan2` is insensitive to the length of the vector, so we don't need to worry about scaling here.

Comment: Thanks, I  believe this will work in the files I have now. I do have sheer in places, though in my immediate problem I do not.

Comment: With shearing in play, then there are multiple equally-valid ways to break down a given matrix into a rotation and a shear, so you'll need to provide some additional details we can use to select a canonical decomposition.

Comment: Is there a way to project the final rotation onto the Z-axis maybe? The added knowledge we have is that we know it can be represented with a Z-axis rotation only.

Also, I'm having trouble with the Atan2 approach, it's returning 30 degrees for the values in the question.

Comment: If you're saying that even rotation about Z is ambiguous with sheering, then I'll have to prevent sheering.

Comment: Sorry, I have the Atan2 backwards, it is correct.

Comment: Yeah, it always mixes me up that Atan2 puts y before x - I guess it's reading the numerator before the denominator. And yes, rotation + shearing = ambiguity, even in 2D (z rotation only). Also, if this solution worked for you, be sure to click the checkmark to mark it as Accepted.